# "verifyTextPresent" is giving me a wrong result when I run the code in Java

Tags: java, selenium

I used Selenium IDE to create a recorded test and one of the commands used was verifyTextPresent. The IDE says there is an error if the text is changed (which is what is expected).

I put the recorded test into Eclipse and ran it, the results says it passed.

Now I have put in different values and never changed the values in my code, but eclipse says it runs fine with no errors. But when I run it in the IDE, it says there are errors and it highlights where the error is.

How come it does not fail on Eclipse when different values are entered for the verifyTextPresent?

Here is the code I use;

```
public class MarvinDataTest extends SeleneseTestBase
{
private Selenium selenium;
private String success = "success";

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://localhost:8000/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testMarvinDataTest() throws Exception 
{
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/displacement/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/displacement/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/displacement/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    ***verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("\"displacement\": 20,"));***
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/humidity/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/humidity/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/humidity/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/load/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/load/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/load/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    ***verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("\"load\": 4,"));***
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/pressure/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/pressure/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/pressure/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/temperature/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/temperature/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/temperature/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("\"temperature\": 17"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/vibration/286");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/vibration/287");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics/vibration/288");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    ***verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("\"vibration\": 4"));***
    selenium.open("/eem/api/v1/metrics");
    assertEquals("", selenium.getTitle());
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("success"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("mm"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("%"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("kg"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("N/m"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("C"));
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("G"));
    selenium.addScript("", "");     
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception 
{
    selenium.stop();
}
}
```

The lines with the asterisks have the wrong data in it and should show up false. It shows an error when using the IDE but when using Eclipse it says it has passed with no errors.

Can somebody please explain this and help me with finding a solution?

Comment: could you show us the actual commands and html you are testing against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed you've tried giving incorrect values using only `verifyTrue`, this actually wont fail a step...You can use `assertTrue` for this purpose..

`verifyTrue`

- is a part of the SeleneseTestCase class and is a SeleniumAPI
- will not fail the test step where you are calling VerifyTrue
- can include verifyTrue in a condition like if

  (verifyTrue( sel.isTextPresent("text to search")) { .... }

`assertTrue`

- part of JUnit API
- the test step will fail if an assertion fails
- cannot be included in any other command

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to make the test fail when it runs on eclipse.
In the testMarvinDataTest method, put in the checkForVerificationErrors() method at the bottom. That now fails the test and shows an error